# urllib is not defined - cannot import "urllib.request import urlopen"

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I'm receiving an error "NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined".  However I'm trying to import urlopen however it is greyed out (2nd line of code is greyed out in Intellij because it deems it unnecessary).  Am I importing it incorrectly?  Or is there something else in my code that is causing the error?

Please review my code and provide assistance.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen


class ContentParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.tagList = []
        self.wordDictionary = {}

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.tagList.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.tagList.pop()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if len(self.tagList) > 0 and (self.tagList[-1]) not in ["script"]:
            self.AddContents(data)

    def AddContents(self, data):
        data = self.RemoveSpecialChar(data)
        contents = data.split()
        for word in contents:
            word = word.decode("utf-8")
            if word in self.wordDictionary:
                self.wordDictionary[word] += 1
            else:
                self.wordDitionary[word] = 1

    def RemoveSpecialChar(self, data):
        data = str.encode(data)
        ret = data
        for char in data:
            if not ((char >= ord("a") and char <= ord("z")) or (char >= ord("A"))):
                if char != ord(""):
                    ret = ret.replace(bytes(chr(char), "utf-8"), b"")
        return ret

    def PrintTopUsedWords(self, count):
        sortedDic = sorted(self.wordDictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        rangeN = count
        if len(sortedDic) < count:
            rangeN = len(sortedDic)
        for i in range(rangeN):
            print(sortedDic[i])

def getWords(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    wordParser = ContentParser()
    wordParser.feed(html.decode("utf-8"))
    wordParser.PrintTopUsedWords(25)

getWords("https://law.depaul.edu/Pages/default.aspx")
```

Comment: You import `urlopen` but you try to call `urllib.request.urlopen`. Either just call `urlopen` or do `import urllib.request`.

Comment: Thank you.  This helped and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 the easiest way is to do

```
import urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your method as well and it works!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!